# Cant load or create projects VS 2015.1. Visual c# 2015 Compiler could not be created

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

Visual c# 2015 Compiler could not be created. Please re-install Visual Studio.

First of all with my vs 2015 everything was ok. But after update 1, uwp designer wont start. So i uninstalled my windows 10 sdk tools, and reinstalled vs, but now in project templates i cant see uwp apps (but i have 8.1 apps) and when im trying to create any project i got errors (of compiler).

I tried many things to fix my VS but nothing helps, even /Uninstall /Force and reinstalling.
Please help me ! :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem too mate, but mine was for the creation of a VB console app (couldnt create a compiler).

What I did and fortunately worked, was to go to control panel, go to uninstall the Visual Studio and right click on it and click on 'Change' (this was the only provided option). Then a window appeared and gave me three options, one of which was to 'Repair'.

Choosing repair and letting the program do its thing should fix the problem, at least it did for me.